EClient.reqSecDefOptParams() method does not return data when an exchange is specified - why?
Using C# IB TWS API, API_Version=10.19.04
According to the IB TWS API documentation, the EClient.reqSecDefOptParams() method returns a list of expiries and strike prices.
I can get the list of expiries and strikes for ALL exchanges if I set the futFopExchange argument to an empty string (as per the docs).  However, whenever I specify an exchange name ("BATS" for example) or any other valid exchange name, the method never returns any data - WHY?
For example - this call will work:
client.reqSecDefOptParams( request_id, underlying_symbol, "", underlying_security_type, underlying_contract_id );

.. and will return the expiries and strikes for the following exchanges:
SMART,AMEX,CBOE,PHLX,PSE,ISE,BOX,BATS,NASDAQOM,CBOE2,NASDAQBX,MIAX,GEMINI,EDGX,MERCURY,PEARL,EMERALD,MEMX,IBUSOPT,SAPPHIRE

However, this call will not return any data:
client.reqSecDefOptParams( request_id, underlying_symbol, "BATS", underlying_security_type, underlying_contract_id );

... the only difference in the two calls is an explicit exchange name was used in the call shown above (all other arguments are the same).
Also, when the method does return the expiries and strikes for ALL exchanges, the number of expiries and strikes all appear the same for all exchanges -- is this normal, or could the number of expiries and strikes differ from exchange to exchange?
Any insights would be appreciated.
Thanks in advance.

futFopExchange is for futures option.  For stocks it's blank.

@brian - thanks, but where is this stated in the documentation?  Or was I to infer from the argument name?  Also - is the number of expiries and strikes always the same for all exchanges?

This is kind of how the API works, you try stuff and figure it out.  I just happened to remember this quirk.  A search here https://groups.io/g/twsapi/search?p=Created%2C%2C%2C20%2C2%2C0%2C0&q=futFopExchange will get some answers.  The consensus seems to be it's a stupid arg but there's no changing the api now.  Some of us have been using the API for over 20 years.

I don't know the amount of returned options per exchange,  I use reqContractDetails since I don't need that much data.  Also with reqSecDefOptParams you have to check if the contract actually exists, it just gives possible strikes and expiries.

@brain - thanks again - I agree, the documentation is somewhat lacking, and I think I will stick with the reqContractDetails method (even if throttled).  Also, thank-you for the additional resource (groups.io); have only been using the API for about two-weeks - so every little bit helps!
